# Why export variables with shell command in Makefile takes a very long time?

Tags: shell, makefile

Here is my test Makefile:

```
VERSION ?= $(shell cat VERSION | grep "VERSION" | cut -d'=' -f2)
VERSION_MAJOR ?= $(shell echo $(VERSION) | cut -d'.' -f1)
VERSION_MINOR ?= $(shell echo $(VERSION) | cut -d'.' -f2)
VERSION_PATCH ?= $(shell echo $(VERSION) | cut -d'.' -f3)

DATE ?= "$(shell date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")"

SOME_NESTED ?= "-X=aaa=$(VERSION_MAJOR) -X=bbb=$(VERSION_MINOR) -X=ccc=$(VERSION_PATCH) -X=ddd=$(DATE)"

#.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES:


t:
        echo "Test $(SOME_NESTED)"
```

And a test file `VERSION`:

```bash
echo "VERSION=1.2.3" > VERSION
```

This makefile works well until I export the variables with shell call.

```bash
# use the original makefile
$ time make t
echo "Test "-X=aaa=1 -X=bbb=2 -X=ccc=3 -X=ddd="2023-10-26T10:00"""
Test -X=aaa=1 -X=bbb=2 -X=ccc=3 -X=ddd=2023-10-26T10:00
make t  0.02s user 0.00s system 116% cpu 0.021 total

# uncomment the .EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES
$ time make t
echo "Test "-X=aaa=1 -X=bbb=2 -X=ccc=3 -X=ddd="2023-10-26T10:09"""
### (hanged for seconds here)
Test -X=aaa=1 -X=bbb=2 -X=ccc=3 -X=ddd=2023-10-26T10:09
make t  5.15s user 0.41s system 111% cpu 4.979 total
```

Uncomment the `.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES` and the command takes 5s to execute.

With `make -d t` I can see massive log like this:

```
Makefile:1: not recursively expanding VERSION to export to shell function
Makefile:8: not recursively expanding SOME_NESTED to export to shell function
Makefile:2: not recursively expanding VERSION_MAJOR to export to shell function
Makefile:3: not recursively expanding VERSION_MINOR to export to shell function
Makefile:4: not recursively expanding VERSION_PATCH to export to shell function
Makefile:6: not recursively expanding DATE to export to shell function
Makefile:2: not recursively expanding VERSION_MAJOR to export to shell function
Makefile:3: not recursively expanding VERSION_MINOR to export to shell function
Makefile:1: not recursively expanding VERSION to export to shell function
Makefile:6: not recursively expanding DATE to export to shell function
Makefile:1: not recursively expanding VERSION to export to shell function
Makefile:2: not recursively expanding VERSION_MAJOR to export to shell function
Makefile:3: not recursively expanding VERSION_MINOR to export to shell function
Makefile:4: not recursively expanding VERSION_PATCH to export to shell function
Makefile:6: not recursively expanding DATE to export to shell function
Makefile:2: not recursively expanding VERSION_MAJOR to export to shell function
Makefile:3: not recursively expanding VERSION_MINOR to export to shell function
Makefile:4: not recursively expanding VERSION_PATCH to export to shell function
```

It seems that `make` is doing something recursively here.

I noticed that the command to be executed `echo "Test "-X=aaa=1 -X=bbb=2 -X=ccc=3 -X=ddd="2023-10-26T10:09"""` is displayed with little delay but the actual output delayed for seconds.

Am I using some bad-practice? Why this happened?

My make version:

```bash
$ make --version
GNU Make 4.4.1
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: A well documented problem. Is your system relatively new and a reasonable hardware spec for this task? (No 486 chips anymore!) .. And please confirm that your system has no other issues with running programs that would suggest degrading/failing drives or RAM. Also that you are not running 95%+ CPU consistently during your test. Did you try rebooting before testing? (You seem like would have considered all these externalities, but just dbl-checking). The only obvious thing is that you're creating a lot of subshells, but it should take that long.

Comment: Everything written here is true.  However, there is also a change in GNU Make 4.4 and above which makes this much worse, when you _export_ variables.  We will try to find a way to keep the feature that was enabled in 4.4, while mitigating this issue.  However, a few rules of thumb: it's _always_ a bad idea to arbitrarily export all variables in your makefile (it's always been this way): instead selectively export only the variable you really need; and, as per the answers here, always use `:=` when assigning variables you'll export and _especially_ variables that expand to `$(shell ...)`

Comment: Just tried GNU Make 4.2.1 inside docker environment. Export all variables takes ~0.1s.
This explains why I am the only one who can't use this makefile from my team member...

Answer (score 6):

If a `make` variable does not already have a value then setting it with `?=` makes it a *recursively expanded* variable.  That means that variable and function references in its value are not expanded until the variable itself is expanded.  Instead, that is done, recursively, *every time* the variable itself is expanded.  This is the traditional handling of `make` variables.

For example, when your `VERSION` variable has recursively expanded value `$(shell cat VERSION | grep "VERSION" | cut -d'=' -f2)`, every appearance of `$(VERSION)` causes `make` to launch a shell, and in it to run `cat`, `grep`, and `cut`.

These activities are individually quick on the timescale of an interactive user, but they are nevertheless slow enough that it's not too hard to consume non-trivial time by performing enough iterations.  And even without `.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES`, you are performing many iterations: to expand `$(SOME_NESTED)` once, I count 8 shells, 8 `cuts`, 4 `cats`, 4 `greps`, and 1 `date` (and 4 `echo`s, but these are likely much cheaper on account of being a shell builtin).  That's already pretty heavy.

But if you `.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES` then `make` expands each one of your variables every time it launches a child process.  That includes for every line of every recipe, as well as for more or less each run of the `shell` function.  Even though `make` is smart enough to recognize and break the recursion inherent in that, you've still massively multiplied the number of processes being run.

> Am I using some bad-practice? Why this happened?

**At a high level**, you're trying to write a makefile as if it were a script.  This is a fundamental error that leads to all kinds of trouble, though you can often push through to get such a thing to work.

**From a strategy perspective**, it's probably unwise to export *all* variables, but that's moot if you really do want to export the particular variables involved.

**At the detail level**, GNU `make` "functions" such as `$(shell)` are an extension to POSIX `make`.  If you want portability then it is a mistake to use any of them at all.  Even if portability is not a concern for you, most GNU extensions are best used sparingly and carefully, and `$(shell)` especially so.

With that said, it's a bit of a rabbit hole.  Supposing that you don't particularly want the deferred recursive expansion of your variables, you can rescue your performance by engaging another extension to make your variables *immediately expanded* by assigning to them with `:=`, like so:

```
VERSION := $(shell cat VERSION | grep "VERSION" | cut -d'=' -f2)
VERSION_MAJOR := $(shell echo $(VERSION) | cut -d'.' -f1)
VERSION_MINOR := $(shell echo $(VERSION) | cut -d'.' -f2)
VERSION_PATCH := $(shell echo $(VERSION) | cut -d'.' -f3)

DATE := "$(shell date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")"

SOME_NESTED := "-X=aaa=$(VERSION_MAJOR) -X=bbb=$(VERSION_MINOR) -X=ccc=$(VERSION_PATCH) -X=ddd=$(DATE)"
```

That breaks the conditional assignment semantic, however.  If you want to preserve the behavior of accepting values for all of these variables from the environment (or from earlier assignments in the same makefile) while also giving them immediately expanded values, then you need to engage yet another GNU extension: conditionals.  For example,

```
ifndef VERSION
  VERSION := $(shell cat VERSION | grep "VERSION" | cut -d'=' -f2)
endif

ifndef VERSION_MAJOR
  VERSION_MAJOR := $(shell echo $(VERSION) | cut -d'.' -f1)
endif

# ...
```

But even that's not all the way to your goal, because a variable that obtains its value from the environment is recursively expanded and can contain variable and function references (nasty!).  If you want to absolutely ensure that these variables are recursively expanded then you need to follow this model for each one:

```
ifdef VERSION
  VERSION := $(VERSION)
else
  VERSION := $(shell cat VERSION | grep "VERSION" | cut -d'=' -f2)
endif
```

### Alternative

The traditional way to do this sort of thing would be either

- to use some kind of preparation script in front of `make` that creates data files or even the makefile itself with appropriate content.  For example, the `configure` script of an Autotools-based project.

  and / or
- to have `make` store build-time generated content in files instead of in variables.  Example:

  ```
  t: unnested
          echo "Test $$(<unnested)"

  .PHONY: unnested
  unnested:
          @awk -F= '$$1 == "VERSION" { split($$2, v, "."); printf "-X=aaa=%s -X=bbb=%s -X=ccc=%s", v[1], v[2], v[3] }' VERSION > $@
          @echo " -X=ddd=$$(date +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M')" >> $@
  ```

  Along with that, make good use (in recipes) of the standard tools you can rely upon to be present in your build environment.  `awk`, for instance.

Comment: You can get the conditional effect without conditions by using `VERSION ?= `... followed by `VERSION := $(VERSION)` on the next line.

Comment: you could also do `VERSION := $(if $(VERSION),$(VERSION),$(shell ....))`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using gnu make, another option is to use make constructs:

```
VERSION := $(if $(VERSION),$(VERSION),$(shell grep "VERSION" VERSION | cut -d'=' -f2)
VERSION_PARTS := $(subst ., ,$(VERSION))
VERSION_MAJOR := $(word 1,$(VERSION_PARTS))
VERSION_MINOR := $(word 2,$(VERSION_PARTS))
VERSION_PATCH := $(word 3,$(VERSION_PARTS))
```